# Datadog log summarization

Tags: datadog

My team and I are trying to add a table to summarize our logs.
Our system logs to datadog (not always but sometimes) as follows:

```
Large operation start
Smaller operation start (UNIQUE MESSAGE)
Smaller operation end (UNIQUE MESSAGE)
..... More logs with meta data .......
Large operation end
```

To group a set of logs (Large operation) and know they are related I added to each a `trace_id` facet (to each log in between).

Eventually I want to quickly be able to see

- total operation time
- operation time of the smaller action
- some meta data collected along the way (somewhere along the way I obtained information I wanted and logged it)

What's the best approach?
I don't want to query each time I need the information - I want to create an overview and to apply the system's analytic tool to this summary

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, this seems to be a use case more suitable for the APM part of Datadog which would measure the execution time and could be [instrumented](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/advanced/adding_metadata_to_spans/?tab=java) to measure the execution time of the smaller functions (if it does not picked up this data automatically). You can then create some nice charts with [Trace Search and Analytics](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/trace_search_and_analytics/?tab=java).

You could also use a custom metric with tags such as `opsize:large` and `opsize:small` which would represent the execution time (a gauge). You can find more details [here](https://docs.datadoghq.com/developers/metrics/custom_metrics/#pagetitle).

At the moment, the log module of Datadog does not seem to support the calculation you expect to see. However, the two solutions above and the related logs can be made visible in a dashboard side by side.